# Setting Environment variable for bash/zsh completion

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, environment-variables, tab-completion

I am using gnu pass with bash/zsh completion. This means when I type `pass a[TAB]` the shell suggests which passwords I have available starting with `a`.

I have two gnu-pass directories, when I want to use the non default dir, I need to set `PASSWORD_STORE_DIR`. To get shell completion, I need to `export PASSWORD_STORE_DIR=~/.password-store-non-default` and then use pass as normal.

This is bothersome as I frequently need to change between the two directories.

Is there a way I could create an alias or shell command that would set that variable, provide the completions and then change back that variable to its original value?

For example

```
alias otherpass=...
otherpass a[TAB]
```

Would provide completion without setting a different `PASSWORD_STORE_DIR`.

Answer (score 0):

In Zsh, you can simply bind a keyboard shortcut to it, like this:

```sh
# Bind the command to Ctrl-P.
bindkey '^P' complete-password

# Create a completion widget for the command.
zle -C complete-password complete-word complete-password

# Create a function to implement the widget.
complete-password() {
  export PASSWORD_STORE_DIR=~/.password-store-non-default
  _main_complete $@
  unset PASSWORD_STORE_DIR
}
```

Then, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> will perform completion with the non-default password store. (No <kbd>Tab</kbd> press required.)